# Storyboard vs. iOS Simulator WYSIWYG

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, interface-builder, simulator

This is my problem:

[image]

```
        Left side: iOS Simulator      Right side: Storyboard / Interface Builder
```

Any ideas? Thanks

... [UI Elements placed in IB appears shifted up in Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335719/ui-elements-placed-in-ib-appears-shifted-up-in-simulator)

Maybe a better solution than this ... I have two xibs with the exact same look, one is shifted up, the other one works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, however. My workaround is to change the view hierarchy and set the UIImageView behind the UINavigationItem. Seems to work.